# Write a program to find the longest word made of other words

Tags: c#, strings, interview-questions

This is my solution to the problem in the title. The code is pretty straightforward. The one problem is with `substring`; it's \$O(n)\$ in .Net and creates garbage. Any other improvements?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LongestWordFromWords
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static string FindLongestWords(string[] listOfWords)
        {
            if (listOfWords == null) throw new ArgumentException("listOfWords");
            var sortedWords = listOfWords.OrderByDescending(word => word.Length).ToList();
            var dict = new HashSet<String>(sortedWords);
            foreach (var word in sortedWords)
            {
                if (isMadeOfWords(word, dict))
                {
                    return word;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static bool isMadeOfWords(string word, HashSet<string> dict)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word)) return false;
            if (word.Length == 1)
            {
                if (dict.Contains(word)) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            foreach (var pair in generatePairs(word))
            {
                if (dict.Contains(pair.Item1))
                {
                    if (dict.Contains(pair.Item2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return isMadeOfWords(pair.Item2, dict);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static List<Tuple<string, string>> generatePairs(string word)
        {
            var output = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                output.Add(Tuple.Create(word.Substring(0, i), word.Substring(i)));
            }
            return output;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] listOfWords = { "ala", "ma", "kota", "aa", "aabbb", "bbb", "cccc", "aabbbmacccc", "aabbbmaxxcccc" };
            string longest = FindLongestWords(listOfWords);
            Console.WriteLine(longest);
            string[] listOfWords2 = { "cat", "cats", "catsdogcats", "catxdogcatsrat", "dog", "dogcatsdog",
                                      "hippopotamuses", "rat", "ratcatdogcat" };
            Console.WriteLine(FindLongestWords(listOfWords2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that strikes me is that you've put everything within the `Program` class, which forces your methods to be `static`, and any program where everything is `static` is a program I want to rewrite :)

Let's start with `FindLongestWords(string[])`:

```
if (listOfWords == null) throw new ArgumentException("listOfWords");
```

This guard clause is throwing the wrong exception, it should be an `ArgumentNullException`. Now the goal of a guard clause is to *fail fast*. Interestingly if you leave it out, the next line would throw an `ArgumentNullException` all by itself, merely by passing it to the `OrderByDescending` extension method:

```
var sortedWords = listOfWords.OrderByDescending(word => word.Length).ToList();
```

I see you're using `var` - I like that. So `sortedWords` is a `List<string>`. I think the method could happily take any `IEnumerable<string>` instead of an array.

Now the next thing I see is a lie - `dict` would be an almost-acceptable name for any `IDictionary`, but it's a `HashSet<T>`...

```
var dict = new HashSet<String>(sortedWords);
```

And here we are. You're `using System.Linq`, so this loop could very well be rewritten with a much shorter Linq-expression:

```
foreach (var word in sortedWords)
{
    if (isMadeOfWords(word, dict))
    {
        return word;
    }
}
return null;
```

Turns into this one-liner (notice `dict` is gone!):

```
return sortedWords.FirstOrDefault(word => isMadeOfWords(word, sortedWords));
```

`isMadeOfWords` should be named `IsMadeOfWords`, and can be happy with some `ICollection`:

```
private static bool IsMadeOfWords(string word, ICollection<string> dict)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word)) return false;
    if (word.Length == 1)
    {
        return dict.Contains(word);
    }
    foreach (var pair in generatePairs(word).Where(pair => dict.Contains(pair.Item1)))
    {
        return dict.Contains(pair.Item2) || IsMadeOfWords(pair.Item2, dict);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I find that's more readable than the more concise form that ReSharper suggests:

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word)) return false;
    return word.Length == 1 
        ? dict.Contains(word) 
        : generatePairs(word).Where(pair => dict.Contains(pair.Item1))
                             .Select(pair => dict.Contains(pair.Item2) || IsMadeOfWords(pair.Item2, dict))
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

And then `generatePairs` should be renamed to `GeneratePairs` and can return `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` instead of `List<Tuple<string, string>>`. The only thing that itches here is the absence of `var` in `for(int i = 1...` - if you're going to use `var`, might as well go all the way!

I'd put that logic in its own class, and then... looks good!

Comment: 1. Static is OK in this case - no mutation e.g. Math.Sin 2. IEnumberable - sure, but only for public interface `FindLongestWords`  3. By dict I meant dictionary of words not `IDictionary` 4. private methods in C# should start with lower case. 5. ReSharper suggestion is ugly as hell.

Comment: Also if you remove HashSet contains look up is O(n) not O(1)

Comment: 1. Fine, but not in `Program` class 3. I think `words` would be appropriate and less confusing 4. That makes it look like Java code; I always capitalize method names but we can argue all night! 5. Agreed, I put it there just to show how it could be written as a `return` statement. And you're probably right about `HashSet.Contains` vs Linq `IEnumerable.Contains`, I can't wait to read an answer that covers performance and algorithm...and Hell should start with uppercase 'H' :)

Comment: The capitalization convention for methods in C# is PascalCase, [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx); [here's why](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/what-is-the-philosophy-reasoning-behind-cs-pascal-casing-method-names).

Comment: @lukas Methods in C# always are pascal cased